# Calculating the enthalpy of dry air using $\rm h = c_p×T$

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

For dry air at $\rm 40 °C$, the value of $c_p$ is $\rm 1.005 kJ/(kg °C)$ or equivalently $\rm 1.005 kJ/(kg K)$.

Based on this two different values of $c_p$ can be calculated:

$\rm c_p = 1.005 kJ/(kg °C) × 40 °C = 40.2 kJ/kg$

or

$\rm c_p = 1.005 kJ/(kg K) × 313.15 K = 314.71 kJ/kg$

What value of the specific heat constant is correct? Does it depend on the specific problem? For example, in page 5 of the webpage at : http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me354/tutorials/pdffiles/Winter11_tut/ME354-Tut10sol_w07.pdf,

$c_p$ is calculated to be $\rm 40.2 kJ/kg$ but if ideal gas property tables are consulted then the enthalpy of air at $\rm 313.15 \ K$ is close to its temperature in Kelvin, $\rm 314.71 \ kJ/kg$.

However, if this value is used to solve the problem on the webpage the enthalpy value in part $C$ is negative.

Comment: You can choose any arbitrary temperature as the datum for zero enthalpy, but you need to be consistent with using this datum in all states.

Comment: user436788, to add to Chet Miller's comment, this means that $h=C_p * \Delta T$ for a unit mass of the substance in question, where $T_0$ is a reference temperature that allows you to take a temperature difference between the current temperature and the reference temperature.  One standard reference temperature is a 0K ideal gas, but that is not the only reference temperature that you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful when dealing with enthalpy. $\mathrm{d}H = C_p ~ \mathrm{d}T$ only holds when the pressure is constant, and is mostly used for phase transitions since they happen at a constant temperature (also, notice the absence of mass). When the gas undergoes a process, to calculate the enthalpy $H$ you will need to integrate w.r.t temperature, and you need $C_p$ as a function of temperature. In general, enthalpy is a function of both pressure and temperature, $H (p, T)$, and the following relation holds: $\mathrm{d}H = C_p ~ \mathrm{d}T + V (1 - \alpha T) ~ \mathrm{d}p $ with $\alpha = \frac{1}{V} (\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_p$ the coefficient of (cubic) thermal expansion.

Comment: For an ideal gas, dH=C_pdT holds at all pressures.

Comment: Yes, it's also a constant, 5R/2 for a monoatomic gas and 7R/2 for a diatomic gas. I think OP needs to update the question whether air is treated as an ideal gas or not in this problem.

Answer (score -1):

The constant $C_p$ tells how much enthalpy varies when the temperature changes by $1K$ at constant pressure; in other words $dH = C_p dT$. Since a temperature variation of $1K$ is the same as a variation of $1°C$, you can express it indifferently in $\mathrm{kJ}/(\mathrm{kg}.\mathrm{K})$ or in $\mathrm{kJ}/(\mathrm{kg}.\mathrm{°C})$. Now, at first approximation, this $C_p$ is a constant. But when you look more closely, you see that it depends on the temperature. This is why you need to precise the temperature when you give its value (for instance here, you give it for dry air at $40°\mathrm{C}$). But it does not make much sense to multiply this value by the temperature for which it is given (unless you consider a process during which the temperature varies by $40°\mathrm{C}$ in your case).